# How to display Url links on the browser instead of console in java

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a problem that how to show the url's links on the browser.

Below is my servlet file nd jsp file.

`Search.java`:

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.servlet.*;
   import javax.servlet.http.*;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import org.jsoup.Jsoup; 
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
   import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   public class Search extends HttpServlet 
   {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static DB db = new DB();

     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse 
       response) throws ServletException, IOException 

   {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();



       try {
           db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Record;");
       } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        try {
           processPage("http://www.yahoo.com");
        } 
           catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }   

       public static void   processPage(String URL) throws SQLException,
          IOException
    {
        //check if the given URL is already in database
    String sql = "select * from Record where URL = '"+URL+"'";
    ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
    if(rs.next())

    {

    }
    else
    {
         //store the URL to database to avoid parsing again
            sql = "INSERT INTO  `tenderMysql`.`Record` " + "(`URL`) 
    VALUES " + "(?);";
        PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, 
          Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
           stmt.setString(1, URL);
           stmt.execute();

           //get useful information
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yahoo.com").get();

           if(doc.text().contains("crash")){
                System.out.println(URL);
           }

           //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
           Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link: questions)
           {
                if(link.attr("href").contains("www"))
                   processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
           }
       }
    }

  }
```

---

The given below is my jsp file from which i have to show the links on browser.

`Search.jsp`:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>
 Select website name from DropdownList
 </title>  
       </head>
    <body bgcolor="8B4513">
   <form  action="HelloServlet" >
    <center>
   <h1> Optimzed Search</h1>
  <br>
  </center>
 </form>
  </body>   
  </html>
```

Comment: Which url you want to print in JSP? this one `if(doc.text().contains("crash")){System.out.println(URL)}`?

Comment: Yes sir...   it should show the links related to crash on browser..

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna just print it out on a plain html page, you could just write it out.

```
 protected void doGet(...)
 {
   PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
   processPage("http://www.yahoo.com", out);
 }    

public static void   processPage(String URL, PrintWriter out)
{
   ....
   if(doc.text().contains("crash")){
       out.println("<p>" + URL+ "</p>");
    }
}
```

**Adding Dependency jar to deployment resources list in eclipse:**

```
project -- > properties --> Deployment Assembly -- > Add - 
-> Archive from File system ---> Add --> Select your jar (in this case soup)
```

Comment: when i try to run .jsp file then its just displaying a content i.e Optimized search...       nd when i try to run servlet file it is showing an error..

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
Search.processPage(Search.java:61)
Search.doGet(Search.java:34)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
 Search.processPage(Search.java:61)
 Search.doGet(Search.java:34)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Jsoup jar file is missing you need to add it to your deployment resource. I have updated the answer.